# Android -How to Remove ViewTreeObserver GlobalLayoutListener with .removeOnGlobalFocusChangeListener

Tags: android, kotlin, observers, android-viewtreeobserver

How do I remove a `viewTreeObserver`? There are 3 different `removeOnGlobalFocusChangeListener` callbacks

[image]

```
class MyFragment: Fragment() {

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    
        binding.root.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener {
            doSomething()
        }
    }
    
    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()

        // I don't know if this is the correct one to call
        binding.root.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalFocusChangeListener { oldFocus, newFocus ->  }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should keep reference to this listener (when created in `onViewCreated`) and release it in `onViewDestroyed` using `removeOnGlobalFocusChangeListener(..)` method and passing listener as `victim`. or earlier if `doSomething()` call isn't necessary to be called so often (once?)

```
var globalListener: ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener? = null

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    globalListener = ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener { doSomething() }
    binding.root.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(globalListener)
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    globalListener?.let { binding.root.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalFocusChangeListener(it) }
    globalListener = null
    super.onDestroy()
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by `using removeOnGlobalFocusChangeListener(..) method and passing listener as victim`

Comment: Thanks for this. 99% of all the other answers that I could find were in Java and I couldn't find anything that was as simply explained as your answer :-)